# Problem with Codeigniter ALYWAS 404 Not found except index page

Tags: codeigniter, ubuntu, nginx

I have problem with my (maybe) configuration nginx server.

In this case, I can't access my project CodeIgniter. All of the routes except the default route index. When I click the other menu, it gives "404 NOT FOUND" error.
I have tried the solutions on StackOverflow and other websites on Google, but they haven't worked.
All of my project can't access menu except the default index.

This is my conf nginx server :

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 150;

    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: the controller on my projects also used uppercase in the beginning name file or class.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons of why this could happen inside CI than with a nginx misconfiguration. Does it work on any other environment (like with xampp)?

Do you have a .htaccess file in the root folder of CI? If not, try adding this on it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$0
```